# ListPointPlot3D Function for DateObject

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

i was looking  for a plot function which displays as function of Time/dates 2 series of different data, something like a `ListPointPlot3D` but for `DateObject`, which could be a `DateListPlot3D` function. Unfortunately i could not find such a function. is there something similar ?

Comment: Can you include a sample of the data you want to plot?\

Comment: This is only an exampple: `DateListX={DateObject1;DateObject2;DateObject3;DateObject4;DateObject5;DateObject6}; DataY={53.2,69.8,66.7,54.2,86.4,62.1}; DataZ={99.8,98.6,100.2,100.1,97.2,98.1};` the Data contains in reality more than 1000 points

Answer (score 1):

```
DateListX = DateRange[Today, DatePlus[Today, Quantity[5, "Days"]]]
```

[image]

```
DataY = {53.2, 69.8, 66.7, 54.2, 86.4, 62.1};
DataZ = {99.8, 98.6, 100.2, 100.1, 97.2, 98.1};
```

Construct `{x, y, z}` triples:

```
xyz = Transpose[{AbsoluteTime /@ DateListX, DataY, DataZ}];
```

Use the undocumented `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks `` to get date ticks for the `x` axis:

```
xticks = System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 9, 
   {"Month", "/", "Day", " ", "DayNameShort"}] &;
```

Plot using `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[xyz, ImageSize -> Large, Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: @kgir, thanks it works fine. Do you think a `ToolTip` on the single points (more than 1000) would be possible ? would it be extremely messy ?

Comment: @Pinco, you can try `ListPointPlot3D[ Tooltip[#, Flatten@{DateObject@#[[1]], #[[2 ;;]]}] & /@ xyz]`

Comment: @kgir, i tried your suggestion but i get the error `dimensions longer than data object`